# collect list/folder of linked workbooks in Excel 2010

Tags: excel

I have a workbook which links to a number of other workbooks, which in turn are linked to other workbooks. Is there a simple way to collect all the workbooks referenced by a currently open workbook? I can imagine coding a macro to look at all the cells that hold formulas in a workbook, checking for anything in brackets in the formulas and copying these to a list, but this seems unwieldy and hopefully unnecessary. Does Excel have any tools that help track the workbooks to which a file is linked? I know "trace precedents" is useful within a workbook, and the key combination "ctrl+[" is useful to track linked data, but I can't do this manually for all the cells in the workbook.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will give you the same list that you'd get by clicking Edit>Links.

```
Sub PrintLinkedBooks()

Dim LinkedBooks As Variant
Dim i As Long

LinkedBooks = ThisWorkbook.LinkSources()
For i = LBound(LinkedBooks) To UBound(LinkedBooks)
    Debug.Print LinkedBooks(i)
Next i

End Sub
```

There are also tools out there to find links.  I've never used and but [Bill Manville's](http://www.oaltd.co.uk/mvp/MVPPage.asp) is one that's recommended.

Comment: `.LinkSources` is indeed the key. If you want the books linked to by the books linked to by (...) your book, then you'll have to write a recursive function. Note that `.LinkSources` tells you which books this book links to, but not the reverse, i.e. it won't tell you which books link to this book.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! I'd never found much use for the immediate window, but this is really helpful. Now that I know which books are linked I'll find the ones that shouldn't be and run a find and replace.

Comment: My first thought had been to just find things that are formatted like links, but I figured something like .LinkSources would exist.

Comment: @dougglancy , good answer. If the presence of links isn't a certainty then [its worthy testing this with IsEmpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa195780)